# What examples of Janitrol heater failures can be found in NTSB reports?

Tags: safety

What examples of failures in Janitrol heaters can be found in NTSB reports?

As a bit of background, the [gasoline heater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasoline_heater) is a small, gasoline-fueled heating device commonly found in light twin aircraft such as the [Cessna 414](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_414).

What I'd like to do is compile a list of the associated NTSB reports for all known failures of Janitrol heaters that caused an incident. I'd also like to note which cases had a favorable result and what actions the pilots took to handle the situation.

The answer may eventually lead to a discussion of depressurizing the cabin of pressurized aircraft to put out a fire. While this approach won't work with some fires, it might apply to this situation. [This question about in flight fire](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/391/8490) is relevant to that discussion.

Comment: I found 17 hits in the [NTSB database](http://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/index.aspx) for "Janitrol" but I don't feel like reading through them all to see if the units really contributed to an accident or not ;-)

Comment: You have to wonder why anyone would post a query asking a question about a search you can easily do yourself....